# How to run Ansible parallel tasks using async and check logs for success/failed

Tags: parallel-processing, ansible, uri

I am trying to launch a couple of jobs in parallel using an ansible playbook.
I have to POST to an http to start a job; and once a job is queued it can take 1-3 minutes for the job to complete. I need to start a couple of jobs in parallel in the background, and then poll the logs for either success message, or failed message, and there also needs to be a timeout. I do have ssh access to SERVERNAME so the regex search part pretty much works; however I did not figure out a way to make it fail when it finds "Started Failed" in log. Tried state=absent but that seems to work for other wait_for components.

Is this all doable in Ansible? I came up with the yaml below.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no


  tasks:

    - name: Launch an http POST
      async: 10
      poll: 0
      uri:
        url: "https://SERVERNAME/MYLINK1"
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        status_code: 200
        validate_certs: no
        timeout: 10
        return_content: yes
      register: response1

    - name: Launch an http POST
      async: 10
      poll: 0
      uri:
        url: "https://SERVERNAME/MYLINK2"
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        status_code: 200
        validate_certs: no
        timeout: 10
        return_content: yes
      register: response2

    - name: Wait Job to be ready
      async: 120
      delegate_to: SERVERNAME
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog1.log
        search_regex: "Started Success"
      register: wait_for_success1

    - name: Wait Job to be failed
      async: 120
      delegate_to: SERVERNAME
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog1.log
        search_regex: "Started Failed"
      register: wait_for_failed1

    - name: Wait Job to be ready
      async: 120
      delegate_to: SERVERNAME
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog2.log
        search_regex: "Started Success"
      register: wait_for_success=2

    - name: Wait Job to be failed
      async: 120
      delegate_to: SERVERNAME
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog2.log
        search_regex: "Started Failed"
      register: wait_for_failed2
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to use `async` in your checker tasks.  You can just use the `timeout` param in the `wait_for` module.

```
- hosts: SERVERNAME
  tasks:
    - name: Wait Job1 to be ready
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog1.log
        search_regex: "Started Success"
        timeout: 120

    - name: Wait Job2 to be ready
      wait_for:
        path: /usr/local/logs/mylog2.log
        search_regex: "Started Success"
        timeout: 120
```

I wouldn't bother with checking if "Start failed" appeared in the logs.  If Ansible doesn't see "Started Success" in the logs past your timeout (2m in this case) then the play will fail.